# Background sound in Phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, audio, cordova

I am implementing background sound in phonegap android by using Media player api. It works for one or two iteration after it does not play. It throws errors like

03-15 15:20:40.838: E/MediaPlayer(6574): Error (1,-2147483648) this error comes starting only
and it plays for sometime and again stops below is the logcat errors
03-15 15:23:12.568: E/MediaPlayer(6574): error (-19, 0)
03-15 15:23:12.568: E/MediaPlayer(6574): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
03-15 15:23:12.568: E/MediaPlayer(6574): error (-38, 0)

Here is the my code
         pauseSound = setInterval(function() {
       playAudio("/android_asset/www/sounds/nyan.wav");
     }, 1000);

```
   var my_media = null;
   var mediaTimer = null;

  function playAudio(url) {
  // Play the audio file at url
    my_media = new Media(url,function() {
    // success callback
     my_media.release();     
  });

   // Play audio
   my_media.play();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

html code :

```
<audio controls id="myPlayer" style="display:none;">
  <source id="myPlayerSource" src="#" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

javascript - jquery code :

```
function playAudio(url){
    $("#myPlayerSource").attr("src",url);
    document.getElementById('myPlayer').play()
}
```

check this  tag in html5
[HTML5 Audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

Comment: Rather than just a link, can you show how this will help with the question.

Comment: @user3340147 thanks for reply, i have tried this but this will work for two or thrice sound after that it will throw error. And also I need to play game background sound in the interval method